# Rewriterule and relative path to style sheet question

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

The Rewriterule is this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?search=$1&Page=$2
```

The reference to the stylesheet is this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

When I put the rewrite on the style sheet is ignored.  Please help me to write the correct rule, thank you!

This is done in .htaccess at the root /

Comment: Can you expand your question and tell us what is exactly that you want to achieve with that rewrite rule? As it is, it'll catch every request with a / in it and rewrite it.

Comment: Yes.  I want to have the mydomain.com/searchterm/page URL structure while ignoring files in directories like /css/ and /images/ and /includes/ etc.

Comment: Just to be clear, `$1` will include everything up to the *final* slash in the URL, not the first, since `.*` will match any character, *including* any slashes (except the last one, since it's needed to match the entire pattern). This might be what you're expecting, but it might not, so I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you everybody.  I needed a combination of the suggested answers to make this work with my ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to redirect *any* requests for files that actually exist, rather than just the CSS file. For instance, if you had a `/images` directory with image files you probably wouldn't want your PHP script to handle that any more than you want it to handle your CSS file.

These are the "standard" rules to deliver that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These are conditionals which say "if the following condition is false, ignore the next `RewriteRule`. The actual conditions being evaluated are checks to ensure that the request isn't for a file or directory that actually exists.

This means that when you request `/css/style.css`, Apache will see that there is a file by that name that already exists, so it will ignore your rewrite and serve the file directly.

Comment: This is good too and may be better for your situation than what I proposed.  If you end up wanting multiple RewriteRule directives, this approach can become unwieldy, but if you are just wanting the one RewriteRule to rewrite to index.php, this way should work nicely for you.

Comment: I like this approach I will need to move a couple of files into an /include/ directory to make this work.  Parts of the page fill in via ajax and have URL parameters.  They appear to break when I turn this on.

Answer (score 1):

The link to your stylesheet is being rewritten to index.php.  To avoid this, start with something like:

```
RewriteRule ^css/ - [NC,L]
```

This will cause anything in the css directory not to be rewritten (unless there is for some reason an .htaccess file in css, which would be unusual).

Comment: Andrew can you use this to ignore a particular page, not just a directory?  e.g. /ajax.php

Comment: @Kevin Yes, you can.  The hyphen just means "don't rewrite matches," and the L flag ("Last") means not to process any more directives.  So, something like RewriteRule ^ajax.php - [NC,L] should work.